# 'String' does not have a member named 'characters'

Tags: xcode, string, swift

Hello I am trying to create a game using swift. I currently have Xcode 7 beta 5 and I am programming in Swift 2.0.

```
func createBlocksFromStringSet(stringSets: [String]) {
    for var y = 0; y < stringSets.count; y++ {
        for var x = 0; x < stringSets[0].characters.count; x += 3 {   // Error

            let triplet : String = stringSets[x] + stringSets[x + 1] + stringS8ets[x + 2]
            let block : SKSpriteNode

            switch triplet {
            case "DGU" :
                block = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0), size: blockSize)
                break
            default :
                block = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0), size: blockSize)
                break
            }

            self.addChild(block)
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code in my game, but on line three I get the error:

> 'String' does not have a member named 'characters'

I am unsure why I get this error, because in Swift 2.0 Strings no longer conform to protocol CollectionType so I can no longer do:

```
x < count(stringSets[0]);
```

So now we have to do this:

```
X < stringSets[0].characters.count;
```

I went further to figure out weather or not this was the other code that was affecting this. So I went into a new playground and wrote this in it:

```
var string : String = "STRING"

var stringCount : Int = string.characters.count
```

But this still shows up with that same error. Is this error on me or is something wrong with Xcode 7 beta 5 and Swift 2.0. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I have tried your code in a playground and it works correctly. Make sure, you use Xcode 7.

Comment: Tried your code in online swift2.0 compiler http://swiftstub.com/ , Its working fine .Let me install the Xcode 7 beta 5 and test it out

Comment: If you don't need to explicitly access the `characters` property except for counting, you could try to skirt around it by calling `string.count()` instead

Comment: I don't know what happened but I restarted my computer and reset my SMC and PRAM and now it works.